# scipy.interpolate.interp1d with kind="previous" doesn't extrapolate as expected

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

a = np.arange(10)
b = a + 100

iterp = interp1d(a, b, kind="previous", bounds_error=False)
print(iterp([-1,-2,5,8,12,25]))
# [nan nan  105.  108. nan nan]
```

First two `nan` values makes sense, but last two don't since a previous value is available.

Now if I use extrapolate:

```
iterp = interp1d(a, b, kind="previous", fill_value="extrapolate")
print(iterp([-1,-2,5,8,12,25]))
# [100. 100. 105. 108. 109. 109.]
```

The last two `109.` makes sense but the first two `100.` don't since there is no previous value.

The output I'm looking for is the intuitive `[nan  nan  105.  108.  109.  109.]`. Of course I can take either options above as a base and fiddle with it. But is there a direct way to obtain the desired result?

Comment: *"Now if I use extrapolate: ... [t]he last two 109. makes sense but the first two 100. don't since there is no previous value."*  That looks like a bug, or at least an ugly API wart.  It would probably be worthwhile to create an issue for this on the [scipy github site](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser glad you agree :) reported here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9591

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this workaround isn't too bad I guess:

```
iterp = interp1d(a, b, kind="previous", fill_value=(np.nan, b.max()), bounds_error=False)
print(iterp([-1,-2,5,8,12,25]))
# [ nan  nan 105. 108. 109. 109.]
```